# Проблема вывода

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код,проблема заключается в том,что если выводить cout<<answer<<endl;тратится около 3-х секунд,а если вместо answer выводить что-нибудь другое,например cout<<1<<endl;,то тратится меньше секунды,не понимаю почему такая разница во времени,прошу помочь в объяснении этого момента,заранее спасибо!!!

```
#include<iostream>
 #include<vector>
 using namespace std;
  int main()
 {
long long a,r,k,prav,lev,answer,pp,razmer;
double z;
int ii,jj;
long long mult=1;
bool f;
bool F=true;
cin>>a>>r>>k;
r=a+r;
a=a+1;
vector<long long> p;
p.push_back(2);
for(ii=3;ii<=k+1;ii++)
{
    f=true;
    z=ii;
    for(jj=2;jj<=sqrt(z)+1&&f;jj++)
    {
        if(ii%jj==0)
            f=false;
    }
    if(f)
        p.push_back(ii);
}
long long sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5,sum6,sum7,sum8,sum9,sum10,sum11,sum12,SUM1,SUM2,SUM3,SUM4,SUM5,SUM6,SUM7,SUM8,SUM9,SUM10,SUM11,SUM12,mult1,mult2,q,w,e,t,y,u,o,g,d,m;
f=true;
bool F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11;
long long aa,ss,dd,ff,gg,hh,ll,cc,mm;
long long AA,SS,DD,FF,GG,HH,LL,CC,MM;
z=a;
sum1=0;SUM1=0;
if(k>=1)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size();q++)
{
    sum1=sum1+r/p[q];
    SUM1=SUM1+a/p[q];
}
}
sum2=0;SUM2=0;
if(k>=2)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-1;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size();w++)
    {
        sum2=sum2+aa/p[w];
        SUM2=SUM2+AA/p[w];
    }
}
}
sum3=0;SUM3=0;
if(k>=4)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-2;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-1;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size();e++)
        {
            sum3=sum3+ss/p[e];
            SUM3=SUM3+SS/p[e];
        }
    }
}
}
sum4=0;SUM4=0;
if(k>=6)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-3;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-2;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size()-1;e++)
        {
            dd=ss/p[e];
            DD=SS/p[e];
            for(t=e+1;t<p.size();t++)
            {
                sum4=sum4+dd/p[t];
                SUM4=SUM4+DD/p[t];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
sum5=0;SUM5=0;
if(k>=10)
{
    F1=true;
for(q=0;q<p.size()-4;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-3;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size()-2;e++)
        {
            dd=ss/p[e];
            DD=SS/p[e];
            for(t=e+1;t<p.size()-1;t++)
            {
                ff=dd/p[t];
                FF=DD/p[t];
                for(y=t+1;y<p.size();y++)
                {
                    sum5=sum5+ff/p[y];
                    SUM5=SUM5+FF/p[y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
sum6=0;SUM6=0;
if(k>=12)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-5;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-4;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size()-3;e++)
        {
            dd=ss/p[e];
            DD=SS/p[e];
            for(t=e+1;t<p.size()-2;t++)
            {
                ff=dd/p[t];
                FF=DD/p[t];
                for(y=t+1;y<p.size()-1;y++)
                {
                    gg=ff/p[y];
                    GG=FF/p[y];
                    for(u=y+1;u<p.size();u++)
                    {
                        sum6=sum6+gg/p[u];
                        SUM6=SUM6+GG/p[u];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
sum7=0;SUM7=0;
if(k>=16)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-6;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    if(p[q]*p[q+1]*p[q+2]*p[q+3]*p[q+4]*p[q+5]*p[q+6]>20000000000)
        q=p.size();
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-5;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[w+1]*p[w+2]*p[w+3]*p[w+4]*p[w+5]>20000000000)
            w=p.size();
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size()-4;e++)
        {
            dd=ss/p[e];
            DD=SS/p[e];
            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[e+1]*p[e+2]*p[e+3]*p[e+4]>20000000000)
                e=p.size();
            for(t=e+1;t<p.size()-3;t++)
            {
                ff=dd/p[t];
                FF=DD/p[t];
                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[t+1]*p[t+2]*p[t+3]>20000000000)
                    t=p.size();
                for(y=t+1;y<p.size()-2;y++)
                {
                    gg=ff/p[y];
                    GG=FF/p[y];
                    if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[y+1]*p[y+2]>20000000000)
                        y=p.size();
                    for(u=y+1;u<p.size()-1;u++)
                    {
                        hh=gg/p[u];
                        HH=GG/p[u];
                        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[u+1]>20000000000)
                            u=p.size();
                        for(o=u+1;o<p.size();o++)
                        {
                            sum7=sum7+hh/p[o];
                            SUM7=SUM7+HH/p[o];
                            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]>20000000000)
                                o=p.size();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
sum8=0;SUM8=0;
if(k>=18)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-7;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    if(p[q]*p[q+1]*p[q+2]*p[q+3]*p[q+4]*p[q+5]*p[q+6]*p[q+7]>20000000000)
        q=p.size();
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-6;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[w+1]*p[w+2]*p[w+3]*p[w+4]*p[w+5]*p[w+6]>20000000000)
            w=p.size();
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size()-5;e++)
        {
            dd=ss/p[e];
            DD=SS/p[e];
            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[e+1]*p[e+2]*p[e+3]*p[e+4]*p[e+5]>20000000000)
                e=p.size();
            for(t=e+1;t<p.size()-4;t++)
            {
                ff=dd/p[t];
                FF=DD/p[t];
                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[t+1]*p[t+2]*p[t+3]*p[t+4]>20000000000)
                    t=p.size();
                for(y=t+1;y<p.size()-3;y++)
                {
                    gg=ff/p[y];
                    GG=FF/p[y];
                    if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[y+1]*p[y+2]*p[y+3]>20000000000)
                        y=p.size();
                    for(u=y+1;u<p.size()-2;u++)
                    {
                        hh=gg/p[u];
                        HH=GG/p[u];
                        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[u+1]*p[u+2]>20000000000)
                            u=p.size();
                        for(o=u+1;o<p.size()-1;o++)
                        {
                            ll=hh/p[o];
                            LL=HH/p[o];
                            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[o+1]>20000000000)
                                o=p.size();
                            for(g=o+1;g<p.size();g++)
                            {
                                sum8=sum8+ll/p[g];
                                SUM8=SUM8+LL/p[g];
                                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[g]>20000000000)
                                    g=p.size();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
sum9=0;SUM9=0;
    if(k>=22)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-8;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    if(p[q]*p[q+1]*p[q+2]*p[q+3]*p[q+4]*p[q+5]*p[q+6]*p[q+7]*p[q+8]>20000000000)
        q=p.size();
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-7;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[w+1]*p[w+2]*p[w+3]*p[w+4]*p[w+5]*p[w+6]*p[w+7]>20000000000)
            w=p.size();
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size()-6;e++)
        {
            dd=ss/p[e];
            DD=SS/p[e];
            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[e+1]*p[e+2]*p[e+3]*p[e+4]*p[e+5]*p[e+6]>20000000000)
                e=p.size();
            for(t=e+1;t<p.size()-5;t++)
            {
                ff=dd/p[t];
                FF=DD/p[t];
                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[t+1]*p[t+2]*p[t+3]*p[t+4]*p[t+5]>20000000000)
                    t=p.size();
                for(y=t+1;y<p.size()-4;y++)
                {
                    gg=ff/p[y];
                    GG=FF/p[y];
                    if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[y+1]*p[y+2]*p[y+3]*p[y+4]>20000000000)
                        y=p.size();
                    for(u=y+1;u<p.size()-3;u++)
                    {
                        hh=gg/p[u];
                        HH=GG/p[u];
                        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[u+1]*p[u+2]*p[u+3]>20000000000)
                            u=p.size();
                        for(o=u+1;o<p.size()-2;o++)
                        {
                            ll=hh/p[o];
                            LL=HH/p[o];
                            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[o+1]*p[o+2]>20000000000)
                                o=p.size();
                            for(g=o+1;g<p.size()-1;g++)
                            {
                                cc=ll/p[g];
                                CC=LL/p[g];
                                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[g]*p[g+1]>20000000000)
                                    g=p.size();
                            for(d=g+1;d<p.size();d++)
                            {
                                sum9=sum9+cc/p[d];
                                SUM9=SUM9+CC/p[d];
                                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[g]*p[d]>20000000000)
                                    d=p.size();
                            }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
    }
    sum10=0;SUM10=0;
    if(k>=28)
{
for(q=0;q<p.size()-9;q++)
{
    aa=r/p[q];
    AA=a/p[q];
    if(p[q]*p[q+1]*p[q+2]*p[q+3]*p[q+4]*p[q+5]*p[q+6]*p[q+7]*p[q+8]*p[q+9]>20000000000)
        q=p.size();
    for(w=q+1;w<p.size()-8;w++)
    {
        ss=aa/p[w];
        SS=AA/p[w];
        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[w+1]*p[w+2]*p[w+3]*p[w+4]*p[w+5]*p[w+6]*p[w+7]*p[w+8]>20000000000)
            w=p.size();
        for(e=w+1;e<p.size()-7;e++)
        {
            dd=ss/p[e];
            DD=SS/p[e];
            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[e+1]*p[e+2]*p[e+3]*p[e+4]*p[e+5]*p[e+6]*p[e+7]>20000000000)
                e=p.size();
            for(t=e+1;t<p.size()-6;t++)
            {
                ff=dd/p[t];
                FF=DD/p[t];
                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[t+1]*p[t+2]*p[t+3]*p[t+4]*p[t+5]*p[t+6]>20000000000)
                    t=p.size();
                for(y=t+1;y<p.size()-5;y++)
                {
                    gg=ff/p[y];
                    GG=FF/p[y];
                    if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[y+1]*p[y+2]*p[y+3]*p[y+4]*p[y+5]>20000000000)
                        y=p.size();
                    for(u=y+1;u<p.size()-4;u++)
                    {
                        hh=gg/p[u];
                        HH=GG/p[u];
                        if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[u+1]*p[u+2]*p[u+3]*p[u+4]>20000000000)
                            u=p.size();
                        for(o=u+1;o<p.size()-3;o++)
                        {
                            ll=hh/p[o];
                            LL=HH/p[o];
                            if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[o+1]*p[o+2]*p[o+3]>20000000000)
                                o=p.size();
                            for(g=o+1;g<p.size()-2;g++)
                            {
                                cc=ll/p[g];
                                CC=LL/p[g];
                                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[g]*p[g+1]*p[g+2]>20000000000)
                                    g=p.size();
                            for(d=g+1;d<p.size()-1;d++)
                            {
                                mm=cc/p[d];
                                MM=CC/p[d];
                                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[g]*p[d]*p[d+1]>20000000000)
                                    d=p.size();
                            for(m=d+1;m<p.size();m++)
                            {
                                sum10=sum10+mm/p[m];
                                SUM10=SUM10+MM/p[m];
                                if(p[q]*p[w]*p[e]*p[t]*p[y]*p[u]*p[o]*p[g]*p[d]*p[m]>20000000000)
                                    m=p.size();
                            }
                            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
    }
}
    }
    if(p.size()==1)
    {
        prav=r-sum1;
        lev=a-SUM1;
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==2)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==3)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==4)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3-sum4);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3-SUM4);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==5)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3-sum4+sum5);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3-SUM4+SUM5);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==6)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3-sum4+sum5-sum6);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3-SUM4+SUM5-SUM6);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==7)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3-sum4+sum5-sum6+sum7);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3-SUM4+SUM5-SUM6+SUM7);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==8)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3-sum4+sum5-sum6+sum7-sum8);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3-SUM4+SUM5-SUM6+SUM7-SUM8);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()==9)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3-sum4+sum5-sum6+sum7-sum8+sum9);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3-SUM4+SUM5-SUM6+SUM7-SUM8+SUM9);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
    if(p.size()>=10)
    {
        prav=r-(sum1-sum2+sum3-sum4+sum5-sum6+sum7-sum8+sum9-sum10);
        lev=a-(SUM1-SUM2+SUM3-SUM4+SUM5-SUM6+SUM7-SUM8+SUM9-SUM10);
        answer=prav-lev;
    }
for(int i=0;i<p.size()&&f;i++)
{
    if(a%p[i]==0)
        f=false;
}
if(f)
    answer++;
cout<<answer<<endl;
system("pause");
```

}

Comment: То есть я вывожу переменную answer и при входных данных например 23, 7 ,300 ответ ждать приходится три секунды,а если я вместо строчки cout<<answer<<endl; изменю на cout<<1<<endl; то вывод происходит меньше секунды,вот я и хочу знать,почему в одном случае 3 секунды,а в другом 1

Comment: Это может означать, что у вашего компилятора хороший оптимизатор, который выбрасывает нафиг ненужные вычисления :-)

Answer (score 1):

Если результат вычисления не используется, на этапе оптимизации это вычисление может отбрасываться и тело main сужается до крайних двух строк.